# Subprocess is blocking print from executing

Tags: python-3.x, printing, subprocess

i have the following loop with a print and a subprocess call

```
for file in os.listdir(dir):
    print(file)
    subprocess.call(['python', 'otherscript.py', file])
```

otherscript.py prints some stuff as well. so when i execute my main script, everything that my main script should print before calling otherscript.py will be printed after otherscript.py is called for the last time:

- output from subprocess 1
- output from subprocess 2
- output from subprocess 3
- output from main 1
- output from main 2
- output from main 3

how can i make it print before calling the subprocess?

Comment: I am not sure if this will work, but try adding ', flush=True' after 'file' in the print call (assuming you are using 3.3+)..

Answer (score 1):

The subprocess stdout buffer is flushed then the child python script exits while the content buffered by `print()` function in the parent may still be there.

The solution is to make sure that nothing is buffered before running `subprocess.call()`. See [How to flush output of Python print?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/230751/4279)